# Non-relativistic approximations of the Dirac Lagrangian instead of the Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, dirac-equation

Consider the Dirac equation in the following form
\begin{equation}
  i \hbar \partial_t \psi = \hat{H} \psi\,, \quad \hat{H} = c \vec{\alpha} \cdot (\hat{\vec{p}} - e\vec{A}) + \beta mc^2  + e \phi 
\end{equation}
where $\vec{\alpha} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \vec{\sigma}\\
\vec{\sigma} & 0
\end{pmatrix} \,, \beta = \begin{pmatrix}
I_{2\times2} & 0\\
0 & -I_{2\times2}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\phi$ is the electric field. By making the ansatz
\begin{equation}
  \psi = \begin{pmatrix} \varphi \\ \chi
\end{pmatrix} e^{-i mc^2 t /\hbar}
\end{equation}
we can obtain two decoupled equations for $\varphi$ and $\chi$, which can then be solved by negelcting all energies small compared to $mc^2$. After some algebra this leads to the Pauli Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_P = \frac{1}{2m} ( \hat{\vec{p}} - e \vec{A})^2 - \frac{e\hbar}{2m} \vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{B} + e\phi \,.
\end{equation}
In similar fashion one can derive the expression for the spin-orbit-coupling Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_{SOC} = \frac{e}{2m^2c^2r} \frac{d\phi}{dr} (\hat{\vec{S}} \cdot \hat{\vec{L}}) \,, \quad \hat{\vec{S}} = \frac{\hbar}{2} \vec{\sigma}\,.
\end{equation}
These are textbook results. My question now is: is it possible to obtain these non-relativistic approximations directly from the Dirac Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - \tfrac{mc}{\hbar}) \psi \,,
\end{equation}
for example also in the form of a Lagrangian for the Pauli equation (as in [What's the Lagrangian for the Pauli equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/354346/)) or for SOC?